# regex match numbers that contain spaces but cannot be all spaces?

Tags: python, regex

i'm writing a python regex code to test if a string may be numbers. i wrote follows:

```
import regex as re
re.match('(([-\s]*)([\d\s,]+)(\.?)([\d\s]*)(%?))',' - 1, 00 0.0 0 %')
```

this one works. but how to make this example string(`'.01'`or `.01`) not matched? i.e. how to make the pattern matches the string that contains any digits,`,`,`.`,space and `%`, but not matches the one that contents before `.` are only spaces or nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a lookahead `(?=[\s,]*\d)` before matching the digits before the `.`, asserting that there is a digit (before the `.`):

```
(([-\s]*)(?=[\s,]*\d)([\d\s,]+)(\.?)([\d\s]*)(%?))
```